# Python big space between Entry and Button

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm trying to make a login form.
If i add a button to my form, when where appears a big space.
I tried grid_columnfigure with weight=1 but it sets the x coordinate only a little bit lower (like self.NewProfilePasswordEntry)
My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App:


    def CreateProfileDataInput(self):
        Root = Tk()
        Root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
        Root.geometry("450x500")

        NewProfilePasswordRepeatLabel = Label(Root, text="Passwort wiederholen", font="Tahoma 13").grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(10, 20), pady=(20, 0), sticky=W)
        self.NewProfilePasswordRepeatEntry = ttk.Entry(Root, width=35, show="*").grid(row=3, column=1, pady=(20, 0))

        self.CreateProfileButton = Button(Root, text="Profil erstellen", width=55, height=2, relief="flat", borderwidth=1, bg="#30b1e8", command=lambda:self.CreateProfile()).grid(row=4, column=0, pady=(25, 0))

        Root.mainloop()

App().CreateProfileDataInput()
```

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms9Yu.png)
[But it gives me that (beacuse the button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xwdK.png)

Comment: Would help to include an image on what exactly you want.

Comment: Add `columnspan=2` to the grid arguments for the button.

Comment: @Novel Why comment instead of answer?

Comment: @Nae Dunno, I guess I just didn't feel a solution that trivial was worth an answer. SO answers are supposed to be well thought out essays with citations and graphics, right?

Comment: @Novel If that's a must I have like 4 answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add `columnspan=2` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409575/python-big-space-between-entry-and-button#comment83809833_48409575). The reason above happens is that row length of grid columns is calculated for the longest of the columns, which is the `Button` in the above case. When you set `columnspan=2` it adjusts it so that the widget is occupying two columns instead of one.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App:


    def CreateProfileDataInput(self):
        Root = Tk()
        Root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
        Root.geometry("450x500")

        NewProfilePasswordRepeatLabel = Label(Root, text="Passwort wiederholen",
                                                    font="Tahoma 13")
        self.NewProfilePasswordRepeatEntry = ttk.Entry(Root, width=35, show="*")
        self.CreateProfileButton = Button(Root, text="Profil erstellen",
                                                width=55, height=2,
                                                relief="flat", borderwidth=1,
                                                bg="#30b1e8")

        NewProfilePasswordRepeatLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(10, 20),
                                            pady=(20, 0), sticky=W)
        self.NewProfilePasswordRepeatEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=(20, 0))
        self.CreateProfileButton.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=(25, 0), 
                                            columnspan=2)

        Root.mainloop()

App().CreateProfileDataInput()
```

Additionally, note that I took the liberty to separate layout calls from widget creation calls, without that separation your variables are all `None` which may be problematic later on.